# Forming the possessive of a username that is a contraction

Tags: grammatical-number, contractions

Suppose there was a user of one of these sites [whose handle was `Won't`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/wont). How would one form the possessive of this username to refer to that user's post?*

> Won't's answer

Given that [the `'s` possessive construction is apparently derived from a contraction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90088/7795), and the existence of a fair number of [double contractions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_double_contractions), I suspect this first one might be correct, but frankly, it looks weird to me.

> Won'ts answer

One apostrophe in its usual place looks a little better to me, but it also looks like it might be a pluralization,** even though that doesn't make sense in context. This choice might read confusingly.

> Wont's answer

This seems to be a non-starter, since it changes the name for the sake of forming the possessive.

Is the first one right, or is there a possibility I've missed?*

---

*Aside from using "the post by Won't" or similar rewriting.
**Especially given ["Do's" and "don'ts" or "do's" and "don't's"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28671/dos-and-donts-or-dos-and-donts/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first formation (Won't's) is correct. It looks weird, perhaps, because it's an unusual situation, but there you have it. If somebody uses a contracted word as his/her username or handle, forming the possessive is going to look strange. Just gotta live with it!

Comment: True, it's an edge situation. Any chance you have a reference source? "_Always_ form the possessive with an apostrophe, no exceptions" -- Bloom Picayune Style Guide?